# How to update shopping basket and change the product quantity in multidimensional-array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this products in basket array:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>array(3) {
        ["product_id"]=>string(2) "35"
        ["po"]=>array(2) {
            [0]=>array(1) {
                ["size"]=>string(1) "M"
            }
            [1]=>array(1) {
                ["material"]=>string(10) "Cotton"
            }
        }
        ["qty"]=>string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>array(3) {
        ["product_id"]=>string(2) "34"
        ["po"]=>int(0)
        ["qty"]=>string(1) "2"
    }
    [2]=>array(3) {
        ["product_id"]=>string(2) "35"
        ["po"]=>array(2) {
            [0]=>array(1) {
                ["size"]=>string(3) "XXL"
            }
            [1]=>array(1) {
                ["material"]=>string(10) "Cotton"
            }
        }
        ["qty"]=>string(1) "2"
    }
}
```

I need to update the qty for product_id = 35 where size = XXL. Is it possible to do that and what reference shall I use to update exactly that record (as you can see the array with key [0] is also holding information about this product_id 35)?

Same question I have if I need to change the 'material' or 'size' for the same product..
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate your products list and check required conditions to find an element to modify. Something like this.

```
<?php

$products = [
    [
        'product_id' => '35',
        'po'         => [
            [
                'size' => 'M',
            ],
            [
                'material' => 'Cotton',
            ],
        ],
        'qty' => '1',
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => '34',
        'po'         => 0,
        'qty'        => '2',
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => '35',
        'po'         => [
            [
                'size' => 'XXL',
            ],
            [
                'material' => 'Cotton',
            ],
        ],
        'qty' => '2',
    ],
];

foreach ($products as $productKey => $product) {
    if ('35' !== $product['product_id']) {
        continue;
    }

    if (!\is_array($product['po'])) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($product['po'] as $poItem) {
        if ($poItem['size'] && 'XXL' === $poItem['size']) {
            $products[$productKey]['qty'] = '500';
        }
    }
}

var_dump($products);
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail Prosalov :)